# copy a row and insert into same table in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table named **gen** with structure like below; gen01 is the primary key

```
gen01    gen02   gen03
    A        2       5
    B        7       9
    C        3      11
```

I want to copy a row and insert into the table. So I wrote a SQL

```
insert into gen (gen01, gen02, gen03) 
values 
(D, select gen02, gen03 from gen where gen01 = A)
```

and it report error "missing expression". What's the reason? Thx.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
insert into gen (gen01, gen02, gen03) 
select 'D', gen02, gen03 
from gen where gen01 = 'A';
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this

```
insert into your_table (c1, c2, ...)
select c1, c2, ...
from your_table
where id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code.

```
CREATE TABLE gen(gen01 VARCHAR(100) PRIMARY KEY, gen02 INT, gen03 INT)

INSERT INTO gen(gen01,gen02,gen03)
VALUES('A',2,5),('C',3,11),('B',7,9)

insert into gen (gen01,gen02,gen03) 
select 'D' as gen01,gen02,gen03 from gen where gen01='A';

select * from gen;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can insert some row in same table on basic of condition..

```sql
INSERT INTO IMP_INVOICE_TAX (
SELECT * FROM IMP_INVOICE_TAX WHERE INVOICE_NO=1461009999)
```